Multi languages is not working in laravel 11.1.1
I am using Laravel11.1.1 to build a school website, but the Language switch button is not working as the page shows only English language , actually clicking the arabic button doesn't change the language.
LanguageController code:
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLang($locale)
    {
        if (in_array($locale, ['en', 'ar'])) {
            Session::put('locale', $locale);
            \Log::info('Locale switched to: ' . $locale);
        } else {
            Session::put('locale', config('app.locale'));
            \Log::info('Locale switched to default: ' . config('app.locale'));
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}

LanguageMiddlware
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class LanguageMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = Session::get('locale', config('app.locale'));
        App::setLocale($locale);

        \Log::info('Current locale: ' . $locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}

The Middlware Registration in bootstrap/app.php
<?php
// bootstrap/app.php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function ($middleware) {
        $middleware->append(LanguageMiddleware::class);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function ($exceptions) {
        //
    })
    ->create();

resources/lang/ar/messages.php
<?php

return [
    'home' => 'الصفحة الرئيسية',
    'news' => 'الأخبار',
    'gallery' => 'المعرض',
    'classes' => 'الفصول الدراسية',
    'contact' => 'اتصل بنا',
    'join_us' => 'انضم إلينا',
    'welcome' => 'مرحبا بكم في مدرسة الطيف الخاصة',
];

resources/lang/en/messages.php
<?php

return [
    'home' => 'Home',
    'news' => 'News',
    'gallery' => 'Gallery',
    'classes' => 'Classes',
    'contact' => 'Contact',
    'join_us' => 'Join Us',
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to Tayf Private School',
];

resources/viwes/layouts/app.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Tayf Private School') }}</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ route('home') }}">{{ config('app.name', 'Tayf Private School') }}</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}">@lang('messages.home')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('news') }}">@lang('messages.news')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('gallery') }}">@lang('messages.gallery')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('classes') }}">@lang('messages.classes')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('contact.index') }}">@lang('messages.contact')</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('join.index') }}">@lang('messages.join_us')</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('lang.switch', ['locale' => 'en']) }}">English</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('lang.switch', ['locale' => 'ar']) }}">العربية</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main">
        <div class="container mt-4">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 bg-light">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <span class="text-muted">© {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name', 'Tayf Private School') }}</span>
        </div>
    </footer>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>

web.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\GalleryController;
use App\Http\Controllers\NewsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ClassController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ContactController;
use App\Http\Controllers\JoinController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController;
// routes/web.php

Route::get('lang/{locale}', [LanguageController::class, 'switchLang'])->name('lang.switch');

// Other routes
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/news', [NewsController::class, 'index'])->name('news');
Route::get('/gallery', [GalleryController::class, 'index'])->name('gallery');
Route::get('/classes', [ClassController::class, 'index'])->name('classes');
Route::get('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'index'])->name('contact.index');
Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'store'])->name('contact.store');
Route::get('/join', [JoinController::class, 'index'])->name('join.index');
Route::post('/join', [JoinController::class, 'store'])->name('join.store');

also here is my config/app.php
<?php

return [

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),

    'locale' => 'en',
    
    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    'available_locales' => ['en', 'ar'],

    'faker_locale' => env('APP_FAKER_LOCALE', 'en_us'),  // Faker locale for generating fake data

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'previous_keys' => array_filter(explode(',', env('APP_PREVIOUS_KEYS', ''))),

    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER', 'file'),
        'store' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE', 'database'),
    ],

];

and config/session/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines the default session driver that is utilized for
    | incoming requests. Laravel supports a variety of storage options to
    | persist session data. Database storage is a great default choice.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to expire immediately when the browser is closed then you may
    | indicate that via the expire_on_close configuration option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => env('SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it's stored. All encryption is performed
    | automatically by Laravel and you may use the session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => env('SESSION_ENCRYPT', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When utilizing the "file" session driver, the session files are placed
    | on disk. The default storage location is defined here; however, you
    | are free to provide another location where they should be stored.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table to
    | be used to store sessions. Of course, a sensible default is defined
    | for you; however, you're welcome to change this to another table.
    |
    */

    'table' => env('SESSION_TABLE', 'sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using one of the framework's cache driven session backends, you may
    | define the cache store which should be used to store the session data
    | between requests. This must match one of your defined cache stores.
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the session cookie that is created by
    | the framework. Typically, you should not need to change this value
    | since doing so does not grant a meaningful security improvement.
    |
    */

  'cookie' => env('SESSION_COOKIE', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application, but you're free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => env('SESSION_PATH', '/'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the domain and subdomains the session cookie is
    | available to. By default, the cookie will be available to the root
    | domain and all subdomains. Typically, this shouldn't be changed.
    |
    */

  'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. It's unlikely you should disable this option.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => env('SESSION_HTTP_ONLY', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" to permit secure cross-site requests.
    |
    | See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE', 'lax'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Partitioned Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will tie the cookie to the top-level site for
    | a cross-site context. Partitioned cookies are accepted by the browser
    | when flagged "secure" and the Same-Site attribute is set to "none".
    |
    */

    'partitioned' => env('SESSION_PARTITIONED_COOKIE', false),

];

I've tried to make my website multi-languale , but only the english works .

What do you see in the log file?

@Olivier when tapping the arabic button it change and return to en [2024-06-17 19:32:53] local.INFO: Current locale: en
[2024-06-17 19:32:53] local.INFO: Locale switched to: ar
[2024-06-17 19:32:53] local.INFO: Current locale: en

Faced with this problem too.
I don't know why, but you should use the second way of localization - json file in the /lang folder.

check .env for right setup
APP_LOCALE=ru
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en
APP_FAKER_LOCALE=ru_RU

your config/app.php looks like has been changed. Normally it contains these settings as
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),
'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'en'),
'faker_locale' => env('APP_FAKER_LOCALE', 'en_US'),


i.e. uses settings from .env

create localization file in 'lang' folder. For example ru.json.
The key is english variant, the value is localized one.
{
"welcome":"Добро пожаловать"
}


